# Reading number type cell from xls file in golang

Tags: go, ubuntu-14.04, xls

Stuck in getting number type(format) cell value from a xls file in Go program. The file has name(text),Due_amount(number) columns in it. 
I am using the github.com/extrame/xls package.

My code is  :

```
if sheet1 := xlFile.GetSheet(0); sheet1 != nil {
    col1 := sheet1.Rows[0].Cols[0]
    col2 := sheet1.Rows[0].Cols[0]
    for i := 0; i <= (int(sheet1.MaxRow)); i++ {
        row1 := sheet1.Rows[uint16(i)]
        col1 = row1.Cols[0]
        col2 = row1.Cols[1]
        fmt.Print("\n", col1.String(xlFile), ",", col2.String(xlFile))
        }
    }
}
```

The col2.String(xlFile) gives wrong values because column 2 has number type entries.

My xls file contents are :

```
COL1  |  COL2
ADAM  |  69057
JHON  |  4926
BILL  |  22792
```

Running my program on this gives values like :

```
[ADAM],[2089.01]
[JHON],[1913.06]
[BILL],[1962.05]
```

how can i get a number value ?
  Can some one tell me how to overcome this?

Comment: could you give some more detail about the values and what you expect them to be?

Comment: Hi matt.s please check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

I believe excel handles cell values differently if they are numeric.

The documentation is sparse, but maybe try converting the value to a `*NumberCol` like so:

`row1.Cols[1].(*xls.NumberCol)`

Comment: Can u suggest me a better way to handle xls files?

and by the way row1.Cols[1].(*NumberCol) says : undefined: NumberCol

Comment: @Hardy, sorry, you need `row1.Cols[1].(*xls.NumberCol)`
; edited above